# Is this dependency injection in ActionScript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, design-patterns, oop, dependency-injection

I have a Main.fla (controlled by Main.as) that has a child named Slide (a Movieclip controlled by another class, Slide.as).

Sometimes, my Slide object have to call the method "nextSlide" on his father, Main object. To do this I tried "this.parent.nextSlide()", but I got this error:

**1061: Call to a possibly undefined method nextSlide through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.**

So, I tried pass the father object by constructor:

var slide:Slide = new Slide(this)

And, on my Slide class, a used this:

```
public function Slide(myParent:Main) {
   this.myParent = myParent;
}
...
myParent.nextSlide();
```

Is this correct? Is this dependency injection?

Thank you.

Comment: on a side note you should probably restructure how you are creating all this. I like to think of OOP as trying to model something that exists in real life and abstract and encapsulate the information. Since objects in real life don't change then your object should not have to change too much. Therefore a Slide object should not be controlling the Main class. A slide should just contain maybe animage, slide number etc. A control class would accept input for changing slides, and then notify the main. Using event listeners and dispatches is a great way for getting different objects to communicate

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion: yes it is. This is probably the most basic form of dependency injection, but it still is injecting a depency in the class instance. I quote from James Shore´s article "Dependency Injection Demystified":

> Dependency injection means giving an object its instance variables. Really. That's it.

see: http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html

There is of course a lot more to dependency injection, there are large frameworks like Spring built around this concept. A bit unispired, but still always a good read: the wikipedia article about DI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection there is also a more complex article about this from Martin Fowler, its older and to be honest, when I read it the first time, I had no idea what he is talking about http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Answer (score 1):

It is correct in the sense that it will work. But you can also cast the `parent` property to the `Main` type, after which you can call the `nextSlide` method:

```
Main(this.parent).nextSlide();
```

This way you tells the compiler to treat the `parent` property as a `Main` object. If the `parent` property is not a `Main` object you will get an error at run-time.

I wouldn't call what you are doing dependency injection.